# Node & Npm not recognized by WebStorm's terminal

Tags: node.js, windows, environment-variables, webstorm

I have paths to Node and NPM in both my user defined environment variable `PATH` and in system variable `Path`.

For node:   `C:\Program Files\nodejs`

For npm:    `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Now `node` and `npm` are recognized by Windows `Command Prompt` but not by WebStorm's terminal. I get error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Does anyone know what is problem? I could use WebStorm's terminal normally till today, but something went wrong and now I'm stuck.

EDIT:

`echo %PATH%` screenshot:

[image]

```
Settings/Tools/Terminal
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: please attach a screenshot of *Settings | Tools | Terminal* page. Also, try running `echo %PATH%` in built-in terminal - what is the result?

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: does the problem persist if you change shell to `cmd.exe`? Also, is `node` recognized in git-cmd shell? BTW, you seems to be using some very old WebStorm version...

Comment: It is Webstorm 10. Node is recognized by git-cmd shell. Although it is set in Webstorm's `Tools/Terminal` settings, it is not recognized in Webstorm terminal :/

Comment: what do you mean saying that it's not recognized? Note that git-cmd itself is not a shell, it's just an utility that initializes PATH and runs cmd.exe (by default - it can run a different shell if the corresponding option is passed).

Comment: Resolved. I really don't know what was the problem, but I just did a reset on shell path and then made it again equal to `git-cmd.exe` as it was before and it works.  
Regarding "what do you mean saying that it's not recognized" - I meant that I couldn't do `npm install` or `node file.js` etc in Webstorm's terminal. I was getting error that node is not recognized as...

Answer (score 29):

I had similar issue.  I had to select `File` -> `Exit` from the IntelliJ application as opposed to using IntelliJ's internal restart option: `File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` -> `Just Restart`.

Comment: Yes, finally! You solved my issue! Who would have known all I had to do was press the "exit". What a nightmare ...

Comment: If you have the JetBrains toolbox it seems you must also exit this or the path won't change

Comment: This actually worked for me just now. Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem like this.I was working with my project with another computer. and after that i decide to work with this project with my computer.so after moving the Files of project. i installed the Node.js and i had all of the paths about Node but when i was want to Run the project. i had this problem. i search a lot but nothing works. so i guess maybe when i restart my computer the new paths of variable system will work well. i restarted and my problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

For those who are encountering this problem when you try to edit the run configuration, you have to put "start" as the command instead of "npm". By default Webstorm knows it's a npm project so it already starts with npm, you simply have to put the start command after that.

[image]